# Initializing arrays and structures in a function

Tags: c

I am trying to initialize an array of elements to a finite value in a c function.
one way i know is to use a for loop to initialize those values but I am wondering if there is a simple way? I know that they can be initialized during array declaration though but I wouldn't prefer that way.

ex:

```
int a[10];

void foo(void)
{
     for (int i=0; i<10;i++)
     { 
        a[i] = 10;
     }
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: What "simple way" specifically do you have in mind? I think the loop is fairly simple already. For structs, a _compound initializer_ will be best. Note: better practise is to pass the object to initialize to the function. Do not use global variables unless really required.

Comment: A loop is fine. Consider this: You have a function, you currently have no parameters. Perhaps using that function and supply parameters to perform your task `void fill(int ar[], size_t len, int value)` and toss your loop in. Let the optimizer sort it out for you. You'd be surprised what the optimizer will do for you if you give it a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the special case, that it is an char/byte array you could use the memset function:

```
#include <string.h>
void * memset ( void * ptr, int value, size_t num );
```

Attention: Thoug an 'int' is passed to memset, the ptr will increase in char/byte steps. So it is not suitable for an int array!

But you could use memfill:

```
#include <publib.h>
void *memfill(void *buf, size_t size, const void *pat, size_t patsize);
```

See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man3/memfill.3pub.html for details. But it is probably not everywhere available.

Comment: @Mac,  MiCo and olaf , Thanks a lot for your suggestions. Greatly appreciate that.

Comment: Hi I would like to extend this discuss for initializing structures (deep initialization). Any suggestions on this?